# What should be done with two questions with little difference?

Tags: discussion, questions

Consider these two questions : [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154141/new-method-to-mainwindow-is-not-visible) and [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156775/call-mainwindow-new-function-by-having-reference-to-uimainwindow).

The OP had an initial question regarding the visibility of a method while calling it which was answered successfully and the answer was accepted.

Then, the OP wanted to know what should be done if the method being called was static, a question which he raised in the comment of the accepted answer.( The answer-er replied to that as well )

Probably not satisfied, the OP went ahead and raised the second question.

Is that okay or should it be considered a duplicate of the first one since there is very little difference in the 2 questions.

Also, since the person answering was trying to clarify his doubt in the comments, I felt that creating another question for this was unnecessary.

What should be the action for this :

- Mark as Duplicate.
- Simple Downvote
- Let it be ?

NOTE 1 : Both his questions seem to have the XY problem according to me.

NOTE 2 : Since, this is my first question on meta, please feel free to suggest the correct tags for the question.

Comment: I don't think an answer in a comment is a real answer. Unless the answer alone from Question 1 directly answers Question 2 I don't think they should be marked as duplicates. 
On top of that, it doesn't look like either question has enough information to give a complete answer.

Comment: But isn't it "almost" in the scope of the first question. Is it okay to raise two such questions on a single day in such a short span of time ?

Comment: Could a single answer solve both questions?

Comment: Also, I don't think the time questions were posted matters. Either the two questions are well written and distinct enough to live on their own, or they should be closed. The time span between two questions does not have an effect on whether it should be closed or not.

Comment: I don't know enough about the tech to say for sure whether they're dupes or not, but @IncreasinglyIdiotic Has the right of it. If they can both be answered by the same answer, they're dupes. If they can't be, then the second question is a follow-up, which is allowed. That they were posted the same day is not a factor in this. (It could indicate lower quality on the second question, but it does not guarantee it.)

Comment: What really, really bugs me though that is the person asking the questions has 3k+ rep, but has never answered a question in their lives, and most of their questions are.... hmmm... Well kind of the equivalent of karma-whoring on reddit.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic : I think if the question is framed "properly", then a single answer can solve both questions. Good to know about the time span thing though.

Comment: @Ash : I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @Ash maybe they are using two accounts, one for asking, one for answering.

Comment: @Cœur That may be, but that was not my point. I just think you shouldn't be able to gain that much reputation just by asking questions. But anyway, good for him/her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I know of C++ (its been 10 years) and what I can tell from the question and this part of the answer:

> You added method `st` to `MainWindow` class, but attempting to call method `st` on object `ui` which type is `Ui::MainWindow` - Qt autogenerated class.

That's true for both questions. Just that in the second question `st` is now `nst` and `ui` is now `inst`. But both `ui` and `inst` are objects of type `Ui::MainWindow`, meaning...

## It's a duplicate